# Choosing a AES key in order to get a given output from the input

Tags: cryptography

I am studying cryptography, and curious if it would be possible to have the input turned into something that I could control, given that I could use any key. And how should I compute it?

example of what I mean: With input "123" I want to have the output "456", what key should I use ?

Comment: This is a very hard problem that, if solvable, would imply that the encryption algorithm was broken.

Comment: Have a look at a variant of the One Time Pad, where rather than a random key you select the key byte by byte to produce your desired output.  As @President Polk points out this is not secure and has all the key exchange problems that apply to the OTP.  A Vigenere cipher with a carefully selected key the same length as the plaintext is effectively the same and again is insecure with the same key exchange problem.